# The inline style is not working when I tried to attached as e-mail content

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-email

I just created simple html table and Opened in the browser which looks like below:

**browser view: (Expected One)**

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<html>

${imageHeader}
<body>
        <div>
            <br> ${suite}</b> For Daily Run : <br> <br>
           <b>${exeDate}</b>. Kindly analyse the failures.
        </div>
        <br>
       
        <table class="styled-table" style=" border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: 25px 0;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    width: 80%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center; padding: 5px 10px;border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd; border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;overflow:hidden;">
    <thead style="background-color: #009879;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;height: 5px;
       line-height: 10px;">
        <tr style="
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd; height:30%;">
            <th style=" padding: 5px 10px; border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;border: 0.8px solid black;overflow:hidden;">S.NO</th>
            <th style=" padding: 5px 10px; border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;border: 0.8px solid black;overflow:hidden;">TOTAL TEST CASES</th>
            <th style=" padding: 5px 10px; border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;border: 0.8px solid black;overflow:hidden;">PASSED TEST CASES</th>
            <th style=" padding: 5px 10px; border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;border: 0.8px solid black;overflow:hidden;">FAILED TEST CASES</th>
            <th style=" padding: 5px 10px; border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;border: 0.8px solid black;overflow:hidden;">PASS PERCENTAGE(%)</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody style="border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;">
        <tr style="color: #696969;text-align: center;border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;">
            <td style="text-align:center;border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;border: 0.8px solid black; overflow:hidden;">01</td>
            <td style="text-align:center;border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;border: 0.8px solid black; overflow:hidden;">450</td>
            <td style="text-align:center;border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;border: 0.8px solid black;overflow:hidden;">300</td>
            <td style="text-align:center;border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;border: 0.8px solid black;overflow:hidden;">150</td>
            <td style="text-align:center;border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;border: 0.8px solid black;overflow:hidden;">80</td>
        </tr>
        <!-- and so on... -->
    </tbody>
</table>
   
        <div>
            <br><br><b>QA Team</b>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I thought everything looks good and now I just want to use this html to embedded as email content to send the status to stakeholders.

After successfully integrated as e-mail content and the html looks like below:

**HTML view as E-mail content: (Not Expected)**

[image]

The table header is look huge in the e-mail content, but the same is looking good in the browser.

How can I reduce the size of header and make it that it looks like in the browser.

Comment: Looks like the default CSS values are different in email clients. A first attempt would be to adjust cell padding with [`padding: ...`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding)

Comment: See [Word HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338201(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) for supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties in Outlook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a height:30% on the `<tr>` that might be adding height.

You've also got padding, so remove that. Perhaps you want top and bottom 0, but left and right 5px so the words are not right up against each other. That would be: `padding:0 5px` on your `<th>'s`.

The final thing that can interfere is the line-height. Make sure your line-height is the same as the font-size if they're all always going to be on one line (check on a mobile too!), or otherwise set it about 4px higher than the font-size so it's not defaulting to something large. It's best to put the result, e.g. `font-size:16px; line-height:20px`, on the `<table style="...">` so everything under it inherits that (and I'm assuming you don't use other styles that override this, as it should all be inline).